# Detecting centered item inside LazyRow in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a horizontal list with a carousel-like effect, the middle item must be positioned at the center of the screen, with the previous and next items showing only their edges. Additionally, the centered item should be slightly scaled up to emphasize its central position,  see the gif below.

[image]

I also want to change the background color when the item is at the center, but it's not working for me, my attempt below kinda works, sometimes it's slow and sometimes it just doesn't work.

Can you please enhance it so the centered item automatically gets updated and scaled?

**My Code:**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyCards(list: List<String>) {

    val state = rememberLazyListState()
    val snappingLayout = remember(state) { SnapLayoutInfoProvider(state) }
    val flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(snappingLayout)

     LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            state = state,
            flingBehavior = flingBehavior
        ) {
            items(list) {
                MyCard(state,list.indexOf(it))
            }
        }

}


@Composable
private fun MyCard(state: LazyListState, index: Int) {


    val isCentered = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val itemInfo = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index}

    itemInfo?.let {
        val center = state.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset / 2
        val childCenter = it.offset + it.size / 2
        val target = childCenter - center
        if (index == target) isCentered.value = true
    }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(10.dp, 10.dp, 10.dp, 200.dp),
        elevation = 5.dp,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        backgroundColor = if (isCentered.value) Color.Red else Color.Blue

    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(70.dp)
                .height(400.dp)
                .width(100.dp)
                .alpha(0f),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ico_main),
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `Card` you can use something like:

```
val backgroundColor by remember {
    derivedStateOf {

        val layoutInfo = state.layoutInfo
        val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
        val itemInfo = visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index}

        itemInfo?.let {

            //First item
            if (itemInfo.index == 0 && itemInfo.offset == 0)
                return@derivedStateOf Red

            //Last item
            val viewportWidth = layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset + layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset
            if (itemInfo.index + 1 == layoutInfo.totalItemsCount &&
                itemInfo.offset + itemInfo.size <= viewportWidth)
            return@derivedStateOf Red

            //Other items
            val delta = 5
            val center = state.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset / 2
            val childCenter = it.offset + it.size / 2
            val target = childCenter - center
            if (target in -delta..delta) return@derivedStateOf Red
        }
        Blue
    }
}


val scale by remember {
    derivedStateOf {            
        val currentItem = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index } ?: return@derivedStateOf 1.0f
        val halfRowWidth = state.layoutInfo.viewportSize.width/2
        (1f - minOf(1f, abs(currentItem.offset + (currentItem.size / 2) - halfRowWidth ).toFloat() / halfRowWidth) * 0.10f)
    }
}
```

and then apply it

```
 Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(10.dp, 10.dp, 10.dp, 200.dp)
            .scale(scale)
            .zIndex(scale * 10),
        //
        backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    )
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error for the background color variable. `Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.`

Comment: here's a pic for the error https://i.postimg.cc/kX6xt1gx/Screen-Shot-2023-03-02-at-1-22-41-AM.png

Comment: Also, there is another issue, this won't work for the first and the last items, they are getting scaled but they won't change the color to red, I understand they shouldn't be since they are not technically at the center, but if they selected/scaled, then I think they should change color.

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa I've updated the code to change the color for the first and last items. For the other error add `import androidx.compose.runtime.*`

Comment: It's perfect now, Thanks a lot.